# My function is not running, what am I missing?

Tags: php

I'm working on a friend list for my website and I'll need to get the user's friends from the database several times, so I think I need a function to neaten things up.  My code displays all of my info correctly until I put it into a function and then it stops working.  I'm not getting any error messages, the content just disappears.  I have other functions in other php documents working fine so I don't know what the problem is.

I have 4 key php documents inside 1 folder.  friends.php header.php includes/dbh.inc.php and includes/friends.inc.php

header.php

```
<?php  
    require 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
    session_start();
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
    include 'includes/posts.inc.php';
    include 'includes/friends.inc.php';
?>
```

includes/dbh.php

```
<?php

$servername = "na";
$dBUsername = "na";
$dBPassword = "na";
$dBName = "na";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

friends.php

```
echo "<div class='friendStatus1'>";
                            echo "Following";
                            status1($conn);
echo "</div>";
```

and finally includes/friends.inc.php

```
<?php
// status1
    function status1($conn) {
        $stat1sql = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (user1 = ?) AND status = 1";
        $stat1stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stat1stmt, $stat1sql)) {
            echo "error1";
        }
        else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stat1stmt, "i", $userID);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stat1stmt);
            $stat1result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stat1stmt);
            while ($stat1row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stat1result)) {
                $userID == $stat1row['user1'];
                $otheruserID = $stat1row['user2'];
                $otheruserNamesql = "SELECT userName FROM users WHERE userid = ?";
                $otheruserNamestmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($otheruserNamestmt, $otheruserNamesql)) {
                    echo "error";
                }
                else {
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($otheruserNamestmt, "s", $otheruserID);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($otheruserNamestmt);
                    $otheruserNameresult = mysqli_stmt_get_result($otheruserNamestmt);
                    while ($otheruserNamerow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($otheruserNameresult)) {
                        echo "<div class='friendBox'>";
                            echo "<a href='home.php?user=".$otheruserNamerow['userName']."'>".$otheruserNamerow['userName']."</a>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: In your first SQL you bind to `$userID` which isn't set until you fetch a row from the same SQL.

Comment: Oops my mistake, I actually have another variable $userID written above the friends.php code.  

$userID is overwritten when you see it.

Comment: As a first step when you don't understand something, isolate it. In other words, extract the [mcve] required for posting here.

Comment: You can try to put 
`error_reporting(E_ALL);` & 
`ini_set("display_errors", 1);` on the top of your header.php file